# WordPress display posts in widget/sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display certain posts on my sidebar widget using text-- I found this  [display-posts category="travel" posts_per_page="3"]

but it's just displaying it as is. Any help regarding this? I'm new to wordpress so I'm trying to figure it out on my own, but maybe you could lend a helping a hand I would gladly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to enable shortcodes in sidebar widgets.

For this, install this plugin in WordPress.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-in-sidebar-widgets/

[display-posts category="travel" posts_per_page="3"] must be a shortcode for the Display Posts plugin.

Do u have the plugin installed?

If no, you can use this plugin to display posts from a certain category.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/

After installing the plugin, you will need to add the plugin shortcode in the text widget on your sidebar.

Comment: I have added this to function.php add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode'); but it still showing it as is.

Comment: Have you tried putting the shortcode on a post/page? Does it then display normally?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/recent-posts-in-sidebar

Or you can just use the recent post widget from dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You can only use plain text or HTML in the Text widget included with WordPress.

Also, the Recent Posts widget included with a standard installation of WordPress doesn't allow you to set from which category to get the posts, so the easiest way to get the functionality that you want is to install a plugin.

Have a look at [Recent Posts Widget Extended](http://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-extended/), with which you'll be able to add a widget to your sidebar and define a category for the recent posts among a lot of other settings not available in the regular Recent Posts widget in WordPress.